# How do I create a template tag for including template files without parsing the template tags in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, mustache

Im using Mustache.js to fill dynamically the html content, i know that I can use the `{% templatetag %}` tag, but I want to use these files as Django templates and as Mustach.js templates, and also I found te template tag too large for programming.

I want to create a new tag like `{% include_template "templates/none/absolute/url.hmtl" %}` or is it possible to extend the `{% include %}` tag to receive a "no_parse" param? it would be perfect to use it as:

```
{% include "my_template.html" no_parse %}
```

Where my_template.html looks something like:

```
Hello {{user}}, you have {{points}} points!
```

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `ssi` template tag should do what you want: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#ssi

```
{% ssi "my_template.html" %}
```

Make sure to read the note on defining `ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS`.